# Счет уникальных значений по двум критериям

Tags: excel

Есть табличка, и формула

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(B1:B8;B1:B8)^(2*ЕПУСТО(B1:B8)-1))
```

сейчас она считает количество уникальных значений в столбце B. Можно ли сделать, чтобы счет происходил только с учетом того, что в столбце A?
Извиняюсь, скрин не могу приложить, тк с телефона. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в диапазоне столбца В не будет пустых ячеек, формулу из заглавного сообщения можно записать короче:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(1/СЧЁТЕСЛИ(B1:B8;B1:B8))
```

Определяем количество уникальных из столбца В для значений из столбца А (пустые ячейки игнорируются):

```
=СУММ(ЕСЛИОШИБКА(1/СЧЁТЕСЛИМН(B1:B8;B1:B8;A1:A8;"Цифры");))
```

Формула массива, редактирование такой формулы завершается тремя клавишами - `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

Comment: Спасибо, так можно и с 3 критериями сделать) главное, чтобы долго думать не стала формула)

Comment: `СЧЕТЕСЛИМН` по скорости уступает старшей сестричке - `СЧЕТЕСЛИ`. И не умеет определять используемый диапазон, поэтому чем меньше указать запас в диапазонах, тем быстрее будет работать.

Comment: увы, пустые ячейки есть в диапазоне, поэтому СЧЕТЕСЛИ никак. Ну и по 3 критериям тоже не годится, возвращает не целые числа)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос...
Для подсчета цифр используя ваши исходные данные:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ((A1:A8="Цифры")/СЧЁТЕСЛИМН(B1:B8;B1:B8;A1:A8;A1:A8))
```

Для Значений соответственно заменить текст в формуле `Цифры` на `Значение`. Помимо этого, можно вместо `"Цифры"` просто указать адрес ячейки по какому критерию ищем.

Comment: Работает, а возможно ли еще сделать это для столбика целиком? Сейчач A1:A8, а удобнее было бы для A:A. Вот в моей формуле то вторая часть и была для этого)

Comment: @skawn, если указать полный столбец, формула повеситс :) Указыайте достаточный размер (с запасом)

Comment: @Eleferen, в формуле автора защита от ошибки при наличии пустых ячеек, а при указании диапазона с запасом это имеет значение.